# Broadcast SendMessage vs calling superclass delegate

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is specific to Unity C#.

Is it better (more performant?) to just use a broadcast SendMessage or just calling the superclass delegate?

Answer (score 1):

Unity's `SendMessage` is the absolute worst-performant way of calling a method and should *never* be used outside of editor tooling.  It depends on reflection and also has the downside of not producing compile-time errors on invalid methods (which becomes a bigger problem if you're refactoring things).